# Changing the menu navigation label in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently storing a company's email created within a 'Theme Options' page - this value is retrieved using `get_theme_option('email')`.

However, I am trying to retrieve and display this value in a WordPress menu label. Whenever I try entering PHP in the navigation label, the code automatically gets commented out.

[image]

I presume this is going to require some WP function such as `wp_get_nav_menu_items` in the functions file, however I am not sure how to approach this - any advice is appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be like creating a placeholder menu item which can be replaced using `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter

So, create a menu item as `Email-Placeholder` which can be replaced with the email id using the below filter.

```
function nav_replace_email($item_output, $item) {

  if ('Email-Placeholder' == $item->title) {
    
    if (is_user_logged_in()) { //change as per the requirement to check if login is required
      return "Put code to retrieve email here" ;
    }
  }
  return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','nav_replace_email',10,2);
```

PS: Code is not tested.